# Binded feature is not recognized

Tags: r

I am using [Titanic](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4q7EvXM3xcNZjVZRTVHN2l1UVk/view?usp=sharing) dataset, to extract some data out of it.

and then I tried to extract the rules based on Aprior :

```
library(arules)
rules<- apriori(df)
```

Then I asked for two metrics **lift**, and **oddsRatio**

```
metrics <- interestMeasure(rules, c("oddsRatio","lift"),transactions = df)
rules<-sort(rules, decreasing = TRUE, by = "lift")
inspect(head(rules ))
head(metrics)
```

But, I need to sort the results based on oddsRatio, so I did

```
dataFramedRules <-quality(rules)
rules<-cbind(dataFramedRules,metrics)
```

Everything was well before the last line

```
rules<-sort(rules, decreasing = TRUE, by = "oddsRatio")
```

but in the last line it complains with:

> Error in `[.data.frame`(x, order(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing)) : 
>         undefined columns selected

it seems that it cannot recognized the binded column `oddsRatio`.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem get solved by the following code:

```
quality(rules) <- cbind(quality(rules), oddsRatio = interestMeasure(rules, measure ="oddsRatio", df))
inspect(head(sort(rules, by = "oddsRatio")))
```